# File upload is not working in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to attach a file but its not working along with bootstrap.
What is the problem?

```
<form action="uploadfile.jsp" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"  name="file"  />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything that moves the files? I think not. Your form is well written and method is post which is right, and enctype too. But to move them to a target file you will have to use `move_uploaded_file`.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";//this is the url of the directory where 
                        //you want to store the uploaded files
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   //file successfully uploaded 
}else{
  //there was an error uploading the file....
}
```